# activemq enable duplicate message - durable subscriber

Tags: activemq-classic, jms-topic

I am using activemq with durable topic subscription.
I am also using JTA and therefor in case of error, I wanted the resend to be triggered by the activeMQ. For this to work, I did the redeliveryPlugin settings and it was working fine until I enabled persistent=true.

With this, now my messages are getting not delivered to the receiver and in the activemq logs, it says that the message is duplicate

```
 WARN | TopicStorePrefetch(...,storeHasMessages=true) ID:... - org.apache.activemq.broker.region.cursors.TopicStorePrefetch:...,batchResetNeeded=false,size=0,cacheEnabled=true,maxBatchSize:200,hasSpace:true,pendingCachedIds.size:0,lastSyncCachedId:ID:...,lastSyncCachedId-seq:39,lastAsyncCachedId:null,lastAsyncCachedId-seq:null - cursor got duplicate send ID:... seq: 40 
WARN | duplicate message from store ID:..., redirecting for dlq processing
```

As I understood, activemq has the duplicate check enabled by default, but I can not find anywhere on how to disable it.
The closest I got was using the conduitSubscriptions option on networkConnectors. However, I have just one broker, so not sure how to use it.